# How do I pass a JS variable into the "value=" parameter of an INPUT statement

Tags: javascript, html, variables, input

The example below should display the value from the JS as the value in the INPUT statement but does not.

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
var qty = 1;
if (qty<3)
{
var shipping=1.92;
var shp_method="USPS First Class Package";
}
else if (qty>=3 && qty<14)
{
var shipping=4.85;
var shp_method="USPS Small Flat Rate Package";
}
else
{
var shipping=10.82;
var shp_method="USPS Medium Flat Rate Package";
}
</script>
<input type="text" name="shp_method" value="<?=shp_method;?>" TEXT STYLE="text-align:center" readonly="readonly" size="30">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

The syntax you are using:

```
value="<?=shp_method;?>"
```

is valid only for PHP.

If you want to do with javascript, you can do something like this:

```
document.getElementById('#textbodID').value = shp_method;
```

Your code should be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    var qty = 1;
    if (qty<3)
    {
    var shipping=1.92;
    var shp_method="USPS First Class Package";
    }
    else if (qty>=3 && qty<14)
    {
    var shipping=4.85;
    var shp_method="USPS Small Flat Rate Package";
    }
    else
    {
    var shipping=10.82;
    var shp_method="USPS Medium Flat Rate Package";
    }

        document.getElementById('#textbodID').value = shp_method;
};
</script>
```

Where `textbodID` is assumed to be the `id` of your input field which can be assigned like this:

```
<input id="textbodID" />
```

Comment: So is <input type="text" name="shp_method" value="<?=shp_method;?>" TEXT STYLE="text-align:center" readonly="readonly" size="30"> replaced with <input id="textbodID" /> which will display the results of the JS?

Comment: @Squotefinger: `<input id="textbodID" type="text" name="shp_method" value="<?=shp_method;?>" TEXT STYLE="text-align:center" readonly="readonly" size="30">`

Comment: Sarfraz - Your recommendation returns <?=shp_method;?> instead of the value of shp_method

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
<input type="text" name="ye" id="yea"> //input box 

        <script type="text/javascript">
        var mytime=new Date();
        document.getElementById("yea").value=(mytime.getFullYear());
</script>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">// use submit button to get input value
```

then use scriplet tag in same jsp page:

like this:

```
<%  String y=request.getParameter("submit"); 
   if(y.equals("Submit"))
   {
    String s=request.getParameter("ye");
    System.out.println(s);
   }
%>
```

after click submit you can see javascript value in your console.
then save this string value in your database
and then u can access this String everywhere.
please don't copy and paste this example. just try to write in your page to avoid errors.

Answer (score 0):

First of all add an id attribute to the input.
this will automatically set the value as soon as the page loads:

```
window.onload = function (){
var qty = 1;
if (qty<3)
{
var shipping=1.92;
var shp_method="USPS First Class Package";
}
else if (qty>=3 && qty<14)
{
var shipping=4.85;
var shp_method="USPS Small Flat Rate Package";
}
else
{
var shipping=10.82;
var shp_method="USPS Medium Flat Rate Package";
}
document.getElementById('inputId').value = shp_method;
}
```